# docker nginx-proxy "Bad Gateway"

Tags: docker, nginx

I have what I think is exactly the setup prescribed in the documentation.  Easy peasy, development-only, no SSL ...  But I'm getting "Bad Gateway."

> `docker exec ... cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

... seems to correctly identify the internal IP-address of the other-container of interest ... which means that scanning for `ENV VIRTUAL_HOST` obviously worked:

```
upstream my_site.local {
   [...]
   server 172.16.238.5:80    # CORRECT!
}
```

When I do `docker logs app_server` I see ... silence.  The server isn't being contacted.

When I do `docker logs nginx_proxy` I see this:

```
failed (111: connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client 172.16.238.1 [...] upstream: "172.16.238.5:80/"
```

The other container specifies `EXPOSE 80` ... so, why is the connection being refused and who is refusing it?

Comment: P.S.  Yes, I have used `network:` in my `docker-config.yml` file and all of the containers do participate in the same bridged network ...

Comment: Realizing the apparent error of my ways, I added `VIRTUAL_PROTO=fastcgi` to the target image but it didn't change anything.  However, I do see that the nginx `default.conf` in the nginx-proxy container *did* change to apparently-correctly reflect the change.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I said above, I realized the error of my ways and did this:

- `VIRTUAL_PROTO=fastcgi`
- `VIRTUAL_ROOT=/var/www`

... and within the `Dockerfile` of the app container I apparently did need to `EXPOSE 9000`.  (This being the default port used by `php-fpm` for FastCGI purposes.)